# Enter as guest into another server folder

Tags: windows, windows-permissions

I have a PC using Windows 7 in 192.168.0.10 where there is a folder, lets call Data, that i want to make avaliable for any computer connected to this network ( 192.168.0.X )

I have shared that folder to everyone and to the guest account.

The problem i have is that when i enter from another location, it always asks me for a user/password, and what i want is that when i type \192.168.0.10\ is that the system drive me directly to the folder Data.

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

Share permissions are different from NTFS (file system) permissions.  Check the NTFS permissions on your shared folder.  You might need to allow the Everyone NTFS group read access.